# NULL statement in VHDL

Tags: null, vhdl

What is the actual purpose of `null` statement in VHDL? Consider the following codes

1-

```
CASE s IS
BEGIN
     WHEN 0 =>    y <= 0;
     WHEN 1 =>    NULL;
END CASE;
```

2-

```
CASE s IS
BEGIN
     WHEN 0 =>    y <= 0;
END CASE;
```

In the second code, since there is no assignment when `s=1`, then `y` retains it previous value. Isn't that? So, I think in both cases, the synthesizer will put a flip flop to keep the previous value of `y`.

Comment: Its main value is to distinguish between "I probably got distracted and forgot to write this case" and "I am documenting the fact that there is nothing to do for this case". If you ever find yourself in a code review on something you wrote several months ago - or worse, something the last guy wrote -  this is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will quote IEEE1076-2008:

> 10.14 Null statement
>
> A null statement performs no action.
>
> null_statement ::= [ label : ] null ;
>
> The execution of the null statement has no effect other than to pass on to the next statement.
>
> NOTE—The null statement can be used to specify explicitly that no action is to be performed when certain conditions are true, although it is never mandatory for this (or any other) purpose. This is particularly useful in conjunction with the case statement, in which all possible values of the case expression shall be covered by choices; for certain choices, it may be that no action is required.

The VHDL language requires a statement for every choice in a case statement: [or synthesis will give an error](http://www.edaboard.com/thread150865.html). [Example implementation:](http://www.vhdl.renerta.com/source/vhd00045.htm)

```
case OPCODE is
    when "001" => TmpData := RegA and RegB;
    when "010" => TmpData := RegA or RegB;
    when "100" => TmpData := not RegA;
    when others => null;
end case;
```

Comment: A case statement alternative (10.9) includes a sequence of statements comprised of sequence_of_statements ::= { sequential_statement }  (10.1) where the braces signify an item repeated one or more times (1.3.2 f) ). A null statement is a sequential statement (10.1) that does nothing (10.14). ***It's not synthesis tools requiring a statement*** for every choice (9.3.3.1), ***it's the VHDL language definition***. BNF is normative (1.3.1)  other than Annex C (1.3.4), where it is informative. Notes are also not part of the language definition (1.3.4).

Comment: ok, changed that. I also looked trough the spec, but they don't explain it in layman's terms that I consider suitable for stackoverflow. Or do you know a good quote?

Comment: Also `sequence_of_statements := {sequential_statement}` (IEEE Std 1076-2008 10. Sequential statements) where curly brackets indicates 0 or more times (1.3.2 Syntactic description), in other words no statement is required). The null statement (10.14)  isn't actually required . The standard requires a choice for every value of the case expression (10.9).