# What do I write in case statement choices if there is nothing to do?

Tags: vhdl

I'm doing this assignment:

> Start out by implementing the simple version of code lock described in figure 4 using the interface described in figure 3. Use the three-process template to implement the state register, next state- and output process for the code lock. The "sync" is being supplied in a file and should be instantiated when implementing the VHDL ibd for the code_lock_simple. The purpose of the sync block is to provide a signal indicating either a rising- or a falling edge of the enter signal. The signal will be synchronized to the clk signal. b) Create a functional simulation of your design, just as you did with the Mee-Moo state machine. Does the state change happen as expected? Add simulation waveform to your journal. c) Create a tester and test your design on the DE2-board, with an interface as in figure 5

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.all;

entity code_lock_simple is
    port(
            clk : in std_logic;
            reset : in std_logic;
            code : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            enter : in std_logic;
            -- Lock output
            lock : out std_logic
            );
            
end code_lock_simple;

architecture Behavioral of code_lock_simple is

        type state_type is (Unlocked, Idle, Ev_code1, Get_code2, Ev_code2, Wrong_code, Perm_locked); 
        
        signal present_state, next_state : state_type; 
        
    begin
    state_reg : process (clk, reset)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset = '0' then 
                present_state <= Idle;
            else
                present_state <= next_state; 
            end if;
        end if;
    end process; 
    
    outputs : process (present_state, enter, code)
        constant code1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1111";
        constant code2 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
        
begin
case present_state is 

     when Idle =>
         if enter = '1' then 
        lock <= '1'; 
      end if; 
    
    when ev_code1 =>
        if enter = '1' and code = code1 then
            lock <= '1';
        elsif enter = '1' and code /= code1 then 
            lock <= '1';
        end if; 
        
    when get_code2 => 
        if enter ='1' then 
            lock <= '1'; 
        end if; 
    
    when ev_code2 => 
        if enter = '1' and code /= code2 then
            lock <= '1';
        elsif enter = '1' and code = code2 then
            lock <= '1'; 
        end if; 
    
    when unlocked => lock <= '0'; 
        if enter = '1' then
            lock <= '1';
        end if;
    end case; 
end process; 

  

                 
        
            
-- NEXT STATE PROCESS
    

------ Hardwirede koder til kodelåsen
 nxt_state : process (present_state, code, enter) 

    constant code1 : std_logic_vector := "1100"; 
    constant code2 : std_logic_vector := "1110";
    
     begin
    
        next_state <= present_state; 
        
        
        case present_state is 
            
            when Idle =>
                if enter = '1' then 
                    next_state <= ev_code1;
                end if; 
            
            when ev_code1 =>
                    if enter = '1' and code = code1 then
                    next_state <= ev_code2;
                    elsif enter = '1' and code /= code1 then 
                        next_state <= Idle; 
                    end if;
            
            when get_code2 =>
                if enter = '1' then 
                    next_state <= ev_code2; 
                end if;
                
            when ev_code2 => 
                if enter = '1' and code /= code2 then 
                    next_state <= Idle; 
                    
                elsif enter = '1' and code = code2 then 
                    next_state <= unlocked; 
                end if; 
            
            when unlocked => lock <= '0'; 
                if enter = '1' then 
                    next_state <= Idle; 
                end if;     
            
            when others =>
                next_state <= Idle; 
        end case;
    end process; 
end;
```

I get this error:

> Error (10313): VHDL Case Statement error at code_lock_simple.vhd(41): Case Statement choices must cover all possible values of expression

How should I write this and what should the code look like?

```
when Unlocked =>
  -- do something here
when Get_code1 =>
  -- do something here
when Wrong_code =>
  -- do something here
when Perm_locked =>
  -- do something here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NULL statement in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876613/null-statement-in-vhdl)

Comment: Besides the mkrieger1's null statement which performs no action a case statement choice or choices selects a sequence of statements which can be zero or more statements sequence_of_statements ::= { sequential_statement } where the {} braces indicate zero or more times in the normative VHDL BNF. Note the case statement only assigns lock <= '1' as yet, state UnLocked would presumably assign it '0'.

Answer (score 2):

My VHDL is a tad rusty, but this error is pointing to your case statement not covering every state you defined for a signal of 'state_type' in this line:

`type state_type is (Unlocked, Idle, Ev_code1, Get_code2, Ev_code2, Wrong_code, Perm_locked);`

To resolve the issue, you'll need to add cases for Unlocked, Get_code1, Wrong_Code, and Perm_locked.

You'll want to cover this in both instances of your case statement.

Answer (score 0):

The case statement in the *outputs* process does not cover all possble values for *present_state*. This is especially nasty in a combinatorial process like *outputs*, because it will infer latches.
One way to solve this is to add a `others =>` case, similar to how it is done in the `nxt_state` process.

To explicitly do nothing the `null` statement can be used. However if this is the correct behavior is up to you to decide (depending on how the circuit is supposed to behave).

Either

```
outputs : process (present_state, enter, code)
...
begin
case present_state is 
...
when others => null;
end case;
...
```

Or alternatively all missing choices can be listed explicitly

```
outputs : process (present_state, enter, code)
...
begin
case present_state is 
...
when Unlocked | Get_code1 | Wrong_code | Perm_locked => null;
end case;
...
```